# How to changed a text based on current day when having a large amount of text possibilities

Tags: javascript

I want a text to change each day depending on the date.

The text is the location of a bike. And I know where the bike will be for the next 3 months.

But there are 90 days, and 90 places. What would be the most effective way to implement this?

I know I could write many "elseif" conditions, but I think there is a more effective way to do it.

Would you have any idea, please?

The if condition would look like this (I think):

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var n = date.getMonth();
var place;
if (day === 1 && n === 1) {
  place = "Name of the city";
}
elseif(day === 2 && n === 1) {
  place = "Name of Another City!"
}
document.getElementById("CityName").innerHTML = place;
```

This requires writing as many conditions as the number of days. Maybe I could use a json?

What do you think?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `[{date: ..., location: ...},{...}...]` suit the purpose?

Comment: WIth that you could do easy  [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get desired pair of values.

Comment: Another option is to use global object [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an object:

```
const locations = {
  "2019-01-01": "Berlin",
  "2019-01-02": "Amsterdam",
  ...
  "2019-03-12": "New York",
};
```

Then you can access a city with the date with `locations['2019-01-02']` respctivly `location[myDate]`.

If you have a `date` variable like `const today = new Date()` you can use `.toISOString().substr(0, 10)` to get that format:

```
console.log(locations[today.toISOString().substr(0, 10)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can structure the data like this:

```
const bikeLocations = [{
  rangeStart: new Date(2018, 3, 1),
  rangeEnd: new Date(2018, 6, 1),
  location: 'city 1'
}, {
  rangeStart: new Date(2018, 6, 1),
  rangeEnd: new Date(2018, 9, 1),
  location: 'city 2'
}, ...]
```

And to get the current location:

```
const now = new Date()
console.log(bikeLocations.filter(bikeLocation => bikeLocation.rangeStart < now && bikeLocation.rangeEnd > now)[0])
```

Comment: While it certainly decreases the effort to set up locations by groupping them, it's error prone - if some date ranges are specified inclusively, you're going to have overlapping ranges and, thus, multiple locations for the same date. Another issue with your code - even in best case scenario `filter()` returns an array, so you need to do `[0]` in order to access result.

Comment: @user11299053 The ranges are just a representation, there is some logic that produces the locations by date range, and bugs in that logic could cause errored ranges no matter how you represent it. you're right about the filter

Comment: If you wish to go one step further in optimizing your code, you may use `.find()` instead of filter. Aside from being more concise, it is 30% faster, especially for the cases you need only **first** match and not entire matching collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do this with an array that contains all the cities, and a function to get the value.

Something like this:

```
        var places = [
            "Name of the city",
            "Name of Another City!",
            "Another city..."
        ];

        function getPlaceName(day) {
            var index = day - 1;//day 1 = index 0
            return places[index];
        }

        var date = new Date();
        var day = date.getDate();
        var n = date.getMonth();
        var place = getPlaceName(day);

        document.getElementById("CityName").innerHTML = place;
```

Comment: I see the logic, but how does it handle dates on different months like for instance the ride starting in May and ending in July?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can create a JSON but another convenient way of doing this is defining a constant `data` with all the values you have:

```
// first number is day, second is month
const data = {
  '1-1': 'city #1',
  '22-3': 'city #2',
  '3-1': 'city #3'
}
```

Then create function `getCity`:

```
const getCity = (day, month) => data[`${day}-${month}`]
```

Finally just call `getCity` with arguments day and month:

```
const day = new Date().getDate()
const month = new Date().getMonth()

const place = getCity(day, month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you set up your data, I would build an object based on `day` and `n`. That way, you can have something like:

```
var places = {
    1: {
        1: 'New York',
        2: 'Philadelphia'
        /* ... */
    },
    2: {
        1: 'Washington'
    }
}
```

Then you can get your names like this:

```
var todaysPlace = places[n][day];
```

But honestly, I like some of the other answers better, like having an object of date strings.

Comment: Yeah, the object seems the best way to go, but thanks